# got anyway i set class inside repeater datarow find by data ID when do postback?

Tags: c#, asp.net

i want set class for repeater when doPostBack for those dataID i wan but dun noe can/cannot?
below code is just for example showing:

```
<body>
  <form id="form1" runat="server">
      <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1"  EnablePartialRendering="true"  runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true" />
     <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server" >
                <ContentTemplate>
                      <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" DataSourceID="dsInbox">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                          <tr id="trInbox"> 
                            <td width="370px" height="25px"><div align="left" class="style95">&nbsp;<%# DisplaySubject(Eval("inbSubject").ToString(), Eval("inbMsg").ToString())%></div></td> 
                            <td width="80px" height="25px"><div align="left" class="style95">&nbsp;<%# Eval("inbCreatedAt","{0:MM-dd-yyyy}") %></div></td> 
                            <td width="94px" height="25px"><div align="left" class="style95">&nbsp;<%# Eval("DataId") %></div></td> 
                          </tr>   
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:Repeater>
                        </ContentTemplate>

            </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

in behind Code C# i can create the class/style i wan

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            if (IsPostBack)
            {
                Repeater1.DataBind();
               //find the data row ID and set class/style when loaded
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are wanting to set a class per each row bound, and need the data ID, then your best approach is to handle it as each row is bound:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" DataSourceID="dsInbox"
              OnItemDataBound="Repeater1_ItemDataBound">
```

and in code-behind:

```
protected void Repeater1_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if ((e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item) || (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem))
    {
        MyType myItem = (MyType)e.Item.DataItem;
        var dataId = myItem.DataId;
        // Do whatever you need here.
    }
}
```