# Change repeater row  value?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, repeater, itemdatabound

im trying to change a value inside my repeater : (via itemdatabound event)

*if the year is empty - set value `blabla`*

my repeater :

```
 <ItemTemplate>
                <tr  >
                    <td  >
                        <%#Eval("year") %>
                   </td>
```

my c# code :

```
 void RPT_Bordereaux_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
            if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(((DataRowView)e.Item.DataItem)["year"].ToString()))
            { 
                (((DataRowView)e.Item.DataItem)["year"]) = "blabla"; // ???????

            }
        }
```

it does change but not displayed in repeater ( the old value is displayed).

one solution  is to add a `server control` or `literal` ( runat server) in the `itemTemplate` - and to "`findControl`" in server - and change its value.

other solution is by jQuery - to search the empty last TD.

but - my question :

is there any other *server side* solution ( ) ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can try something like this :

**Repeater in .aspx:**

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
    <table>
    <tr>
          <td> <%# GetText(Container.DataItem) %></td>
    </tr>

    </table>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

**.cs** :

```
 protected static string GetText(object dataItem)
 {
    string year = Convert.ToString(DataBinder.Eval(dataItem, "year"));
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(year))
    {
        return year;
    }
    else
    {
        return "blahblah";
    }

 }
```

IN `GetText` Method you can able to check by string that Empty or not than return string.

Comment: silly me , how didnt i think about it....  - guess i was too attached to the datarowview class...

Comment: have a look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9820464/got-anyway-i-set-class-inside-repeater-datarow-find-by-data-id-when-do-postback. same things what you want

Comment: your solution is fine , but the link you gave doesnt answer my question since its another issue. i need to set a value and he isnt setting any value

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use the itemcreated event which occurs before the control is bound and not after the control is bound. Example in first link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.itemcreated.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater_events.aspx

ItemDataBound   Occurs after an item in the Repeater control is data-bound but before it is rendered on the page.

Answer (score 1):

HTML FILE

```
<asp:Repeater ID="RPT_Bordereaux" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
    <table>
    <tr>
          <td> <%# GetValue(Container.DataItem) %></td>
    </tr>

    </table>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

.CS CODE

```
protected void RPT_Bordereaux_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
   {
   }
}


protected static string GetValue(object dataItem)
{
   string year = Convert.ToString(DataBinder.Eval(dataItem, "year"));
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(year))
     {
       return Convert.ToString(year);
     }
     else
            {
                return "blahbla";
            }

         }
```

This should work